# Logical Plan to DataFrame/Dataset Apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am using spark 2.0.0  . Here is my code :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.EliminateSubqueryAliases
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan

object WikiDataframe {

  def getDataframe(sparkSession: SparkSession): DataFrame = {

    val df = sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv(FILE_LOCATION)

    df.registerTempTable("pageviews_by_second")

    df
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark SQL Example")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

    val pageViewsDF = WikiDataframe.getDataframe(sparkSession)

    val query: DataFrame = sparkSession.sql("select Date from (select * from pageviews_by_second ) a")

    var logicalQuery: LogicalPlan = query.queryExecution.logical

    println("logicalQuery : " + logicalQuery);

    import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.EliminateSubqueryAliases

    println("Eliminating sub queries");

    logicalQuery = EliminateSubqueryAliases.apply(logicalQuery)

  }
}
```

I am stuck on executing `logicalQuery` . I want to get `dataframe` or `dataset` if possible.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's the problem with the Spark app? You want to get a `Dataset` from...what? From `logicalQuery`? It's not even halfway through the execution process. Please elaborate before I can give you some more hints how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

u need write a class in `org.apache.spark.sql` and have things like the following

```
def apply(Sqlctx: SparkSession, Plan: LogicalPlan): DataFrame = {
  Dataset.ofRows(Sqlctx, Plan)
}
```